# Calculating average items in webshop order for each USIM in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, logic

I have a Pandas DataFrame with the following structure:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'USIM': ['1111111', '2199608', '2222222', '4444444', '1111111', '2111111', '2222222', '4444444'],
    'WEBSHOP_ORDER': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    'DEMAND_QTY': [1, 3, 2, 1, 5, 9, 8, 6]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to calculate the average number of items in the webshop order for each USIM. The USIM column represents the unique identifiers, the WEBSHOP_ORDER column indicates the order ID for each entry, and the DEMAND_QTY column represents the number of items in each order.

I would like to obtain the following output:

```
USIM     AVG_ITEMS_IN_WEBSHOP_ORDER
0  1111111                   17.5  # (28+7)/2 *
1  2111111                   28.0
2  2199608                    7.0
3  2222222                   17.5
4  4444444                   17.5

# * 28 is the sum of WEBSHOP_ORDER == 1
#    7 is the sum of WEBSHOP_ORDER == 0
```

The AVG_ITEMS_IN_WEBSHOP_ORDER column represents the average number of items in webshop orders for each unique USIM value.

Could someone please help me with the logic or code to achieve this? Thank you!

Comment: USIM `1111111` has values of `1` and `5` in your example, how do you get an avg of 17.5?

Comment: Hi exactly, this is where I am struggling. in those particular transactions with id 0&1, we have other USIMS as well and I need avg order count where for example x USIM was also present

Comment: @sdave Can you please [edit] your question and put there the output that is *matching* the provided input?

Comment: @AndrejKesely Hi it is already matching, what is the issue? :)

Comment: Then can you please break down the calculation of 17.5 for 1111111 and of 28?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you need a double [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html). Once to compute the sum of objects, once for the mean per ID:

```
out = (df.groupby('WEBSHOP_ORDER')['DEMAND_QTY'].transform('sum')
         .groupby(df['USIM']).mean()
         .reset_index(name='AVG_ITEMS_IN_WEBSHOP_ORDER')
      )
```

Output:

```
      USIM  AVG_ITEMS_IN_WEBSHOP_ORDER
0  1111111                        17.5
1  2111111                        28.0
2  2199608                         7.0
3  2222222                        17.5
4  4444444                        17.5
```

Comment: unfortunately, this is not the output we need :(

Comment: @sdave Got it, the logic wasn't so clear. Check the update

Comment: works well, perfect. Thank you so much. got to learn something nice today:)

Comment: Nicely worked out! Your edit to the main post helped clarify a lot too, I couldn't see the logic at all :)

Comment: @Pep_8_Guardiola thanks, I also got it wrong initially, then I realized the provided output was actually the intended one ;)